# Do I need a 3 pin to 4 pin adapter for my motherboard fan connectors?

Tags: power-management, computer-building

I'm buying new fans for my machine right now, and it seems that everyone prefers using 3-pin fans over 4-pin fans these days. If my motherboard has 4-pin fan connectors, do I need to use all 4 pins or can I plug a 3-pin adapter into the three critical pins? Should I buy an adapter or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you don't need adapter. Fourth pin is used for regulation of speed by `PWM`, but If not present MB regulates speed by voltage.

Answer (score 2):

3-pin fans will work just fine with 4-pin connectors. If you had 4-pin fans and 3-pin connectors on the motherboard your fans would still work but at full speed.

http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/cs-012074.htm

Comment: Are you sure about that full speed? There is still a voltage regulation from motherboard. Why that souldn't work?